# HttpClient.GetAsync immediately throws TaskCanceledException

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, httpclient

I had a working code that was returning something from my CommonRestClient(which is simple wrapper for HttpClient):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var uri = _baseUri.Concat(AvalancheServiceAdresses.NodeService);
    using (var client = new CommonRestClient(uri))
    {
        var result = await client.GetAsync<List<NodeInfoContract>>(new Uri(NodeServiceConstant.NodesContractUrl, UriKind.Relative), null);
        return View(result);
    }
}
```

It worked fine and i was happy. Until I decide to move my code from view in another class, which should incapsulate entire REST logic and provide an OOP API.

So now my index looks like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var nodeInfoContracts = await _configManager.GetNodesList();
    return View(nodeInfoContracts);
}
```

where `GetNodesList` is

```
public ConfiguredTaskAwaitable<List<NodeInfoContract>> GetNodesList()
{
    var uri = _baseUri.Concat(AvalancheServiceAdresses.NodeService);
    using (var client = new CommonRestClient(uri))
    {
        return client.GetAsync<List<NodeInfoContract>>(new Uri(NodeServiceConstant.NodesContractUrl, UriKind.Relative), null);
    }
}
```

It's clear that provided codes are equal.

But now it always throws an exception when I try to get a result. In my `GetAsync` method it fails on following line with `TaskCanceledException`:

```
var response = await _client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

But it's interestring: when I place a breakpoint on this line and step over its works fine. So here we have race condition or similar.

Why am I getting it? I tried to place CondigureAwait false/true, combining some code, but it always throws an error when breakpoints are off. I checked timeout which is several minutes, it can't cause this error.

Comment: "It's clear that provided codes are equal." - well, no, they aren't. It may not make a difference in this specific instance but in the first version, the `View` method is called *before* the end of the `using` statement for `CommonRestClient` is reached and thus that object is `Dispose`d, whereas in the second, we know that we're called outside of the `using` block. As I say, it may make no difference here, but it is *not* clear that the "codes are equal"

Comment: Okay, I shouldn't say it, I agree with you.

Comment: Why not to wait while `client.GetAsync...` ends?

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev becuase it didn't throw `ObjectDisposedException`, this is why I didn't found that context ends before request finish. I agree that it's my fault, but as I said I was confused with `Resuest timeout` exception description. It clearly wasn't a timeout.

Comment: *"It's clear that provided codes are equal."* -- why isn't `GetNodesList` an `async` method?  It could be about the same if it was `async` and it `await`ed on `client.GetAsync` like in the first `Index` implementation you show.  Essentially, as you show, you're disposing the client before it has a chance to finish, or even start, the communication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second code snippet the client is disposed before the IO completed. Use the first form.

Comment: Thank  you for an answer. It's bizzare that `HttpClient` throws `TaskCanceledException` instead of `ObjectDisposedException`, this is why I was confused...

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy `ObjectDisposedException` is typically only thrown when you first enter a method, Being canceled is more common if it has entered then ran for a bit then has to end early.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain it makes sense, but this exception is used normally to cancel exception. But call method on disposed client is not common, it's an exception. Thus `HttpClient` mix normal behaviour with exceptional one, which is not good thing imo.

Comment: HttpClient often seems bizarre to me. I'm used to better design from the .NET Framework. It's like nobody cared about exceptions.